# How to validate number of digits for json to BigDecimal, but just the fraction digits?

Tags: java, json, validation, jackson, bigdecimal

I want to deserialize a json string to BigDecimal, and validate only the number of fraction digits:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "amount")
@Digits(integer = 9999, fraction = 2, message = "amount must contain 2 decimal places")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

Can I do something like this, but without having any validation on the integer digits?

Comment: Nope - "The annotation @Digits must define the attribute integer"

Comment: I understand that, but is there an alternative way to do the validation, i.e. using something other than the @Digits annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this as a workaround:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "amount")
@Digits(integer = Integer.MAX_VALUE, fraction = 2, message = "amount must contain two decimal places")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

Comment: If this is a work-around, how does it differ from what you ideally want?